# Getting to Know Acceptance Rate of Question Poster without Opening Question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer, users, accept-rate

It always happens that we open a question only to discover that a particular user has a very low acceptance rate. I think some sort of feature should be added so that by looking at the user name in the list of questions, we get to know that this user  has low acceptance rate.

One possibility would be to use different color names depending on the band of acceptance rate.

Say, for 80 - 100 -> Green,  60 - 79 - > Blue, 40 - 59 -> Gray etc.

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why?

Do you only answer the question for the rep points or do you want to help create a great Q&A site.

The only reason I won't answer a question would be when the asker is rude or extremely lazy. But you can't show that using colors ;-).

Comment: Well Reps are good incentives to answering, isn't it? :)

Comment: Gamecat - some of us have limited amount of time available. As such, I would prefer to asnwer te questions for which I'm likely to get more rep over the ones for which i'm likely to get less. It's a way to choose which questions to answer, NOT a way to find an excuse not to answer. FWIW, I think that the proposed feature has pretty much no value add, even if I understand the reason behind the request.